# Get image from Flickr using django-syncr

Tags: django, flickr

I have my photos located on Flickr. I want to sync them between Flickr and my Django app using **django-syncr**. It's installed, Flickr section is visible in Admin site. I can sync photo data from Flickr to my local database. In a few words -- it works.
But, I don't understand how to get these data from my database using views.py and template file?I mean, how to make my Flickr's photos visible on my site?
I got something like this on my site:

```
    *  IMG_2467
    *  Morning fog on Halong bay
```

I used these files but get only title from all data and didn't anything else, including photos.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from syncr.flickr.models import Photo

def index(request):
    get_photo = Photo.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'get_photo': get_photo})
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<title>
Test page
</title>
<body>
{% if get_photo %}
<ul>
{% for photo in get_photo %}
    <li>{{ photo }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No photos are available.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you solve this yet? I don't see anything wrong with that code, did you add it to the list of installed apps in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add `<img src='{{photo.url}}' />` ? I don't see how do you plan to show images if you're just importing the names.